# Knockout.js: access parent collection in data-bind event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say I have a

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: actions.remove">×</button>
```

and a handler

```
var actions = {
    remove: function(item) {
        ?array?.remove(item); // ?array? is a containing array, accessed somehow
    }
}
```

How do I find `?array?` so I can use the same `button` in any `foreach` binding?

**Clarification:**
I know how to do that if I put `remove` into the view model. However the view model contains hierarchical arrays and I do not really want to go through it all just to get methods in the right places. View model is also updated from server occasionally with the help of `ko.mapping`, but that does not add any methods to the new data. That is why I implemented the handlers separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible.

I raised a new knockout issue for that (currently open):
[Allow access to the current array through the binding context](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/780).

Also relevant: [Support for $last in foreach](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/532).

Comment: best alternatives are discussed at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Comment: i liked to do data-bind="click: $parent.someArray.remove.bind($parent.someArray)" see http://jsfiddle.net/drdamour/wzeNT/

Answer (score 3):

You try something like this.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: someArray">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.actions.remove">x</button>
</div>


//Inside your viewmodel.
var self = this;
self.someArray = ko.observableArray();
self.actions = {
remove: function() {
    self.someArray.remove(this); // ?array? is a containing array, accessed somehow
}
}
```

edit: Sorry, I misread what you meant. You can try something like this to make it work for any foreach binding.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: someArray">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: function() {$parent.actions.remove($parent.someArray(), $data}">x</button>
</div>


//Inside your viewmodel.
var self = this;
self.someArray = ko.observableArray();
self.actions = {
remove: function(arr, item) {
    arr.remove(item); // ?array? is a containing array, accessed somehow
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do that, however the arrays are hierarchical and all that will quickly get of hand, that's why I separated the handlers. Updated the question.

Comment: if you don't want to have method remove in every viewmodel, then you can store it within the root viewModel and use $root instead of $parents. Or you can even insert an anonymous function bind to the click binding. Try something like this, click: function() {$parent.someArray().remove($data).